# Reducing generalized eigenvalue problem to regular eigenvalue problem

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra

I expected generalized eigenvalue problem on $(A, B)$ to reduce to eigenvalue problem on $B^{-1} A$ when $A$, $B$ are full rank (Section 7.1 of generalized eigenvalue [tutorial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11240.pdf)), but I get different results out of Mathematica, any idea why? Using Mathematica 12.1.0.0 on Mac

```
A = DiagonalMatrix[{4, 10, 4, 10}];
B = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2, 1, 2}];
Eigenvalues[{A, B}] (* 4, 4, 4, 4 *)
Eigenvalues[Inverse[B].A] (* 5, 5, 4, 4 *)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your reasoning. `Eigenvectors[{A, B}]` is singular, so there's no inverse for $\Phi$.

Comment: The reasoning as in section 7.1 of the [tutorial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11240.pdf) (Eq 34) -- if you multiply both sides of the generalized eigenvalue equation by Inverse[B] the resulting equation has the form of regular eigenvalue problem

Comment: Have you looked at `Eigenvalues[{A,B}//N]   (*  {5., 5., 4., 4.}  *)` ?

Comment: This is a bug, please report this to Support. (It works as expected in 11.2.)